# Mongo Explorer in Web Storm

Tags: mongodb, webstorm, mlab

I'm trying to log into my mongolab db from webstorm plugin.
My problem is that I cant connect into url like: `mydb.mongolab.com:8080`, my user doesn't have permissions and so I get "auth failed". I have to put my url with db on the end like: `mydb.mongolab.com:8080/database1`
I just don't know how to put that url into Add mongo server dialog. It always gives me: "Port in the url is incorrect, it should be a number."

Does anyone knows what to do about that?

Comment: try creating an issue at https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I literally just solved my issue and this is how I did it

#### The General tab

so you're basically given a url like this in your portal

> mongodb://:@ds050879.mlab.com:50879/blogdb

the server url is **ds050879.mlab.com:50879**

it is in the format *host:port* where host is **ds050879.mlab.com**
and port is **50879**

next set user database to the name of your database (*in this case **blogdb***). The Read references can stay on primary.
[Picture Of The General Tab Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb5ER.png)

#### Authentication tab

- set username to your username
- and password to your password
- Auth.database will be the name of your database (*in this case **blogdb***)
- Finally, set Auth. mechanism to SCRAM-SHA-1
  [Picture of the Auth Tab Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ckQ.png)

and then click test connection.

you should receive a message that says connection test successful then click okay. Click okay again to save your settings.. and voila
Now it should be displayed in the explorer

Now you are ready to use the shell

## and sorry I don't have enough reputation to display images and links but click the links to check out the steps if you get stuck

## use these images as guides

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb5ER.png`
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ckQ.png`
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqgcr.png`
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SOfc.png`
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h2iS.png`

Comment: @samuraijack glad I could help